# Creating New Simulator Command Line- Invalid runtime: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Trying to create a new iOS simulator via the command line I ran

```
$ xcrun simctl list devicetypes runtimes
```

which gave me

```
iPhone SE (1st generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE)
```

But when I tried to install the simulator I keep getting

> Invalid runtime: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13

I tried

```
$ xcrun simctl create 'iPhone SE (1st generation)' com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13
```

and

```
xcrun simctl create "iPhone SE (1st generation)" "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE" "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13"
```

I also tried iOS 14 but the same issue occurred

```
$ xcrun simctl create ... com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://suelan.github.io/2020/02/05/iOS-Simulator-from-the-Command-Line/)

run

```
$ xcrun simctl create "MY-iPhone-SE-1stGen" "iPhone SE (1st generation)" iOS13
```

which will return a device uuid like

```
47F03253-EAA7-4682-80BA-C6769471993D
```

then to boot up the simulator you have, use the device uuid to run

```
$ xcrun simctl boot 47F03253-EAA7-4682-80BA-C6769471993D
```

In the Xcode device drop down list you will see

**MY-iPhone-SE-1stGen**

FYI you can use whatever name you want in place of *MY-iPhone-SE-1stGen*